# Put all element values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="class1"><p>line1</p><p>line 2</p></div>
```

With jQuery, how can I take the values of all the p tags within the div and place them in an array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var arr = $('.class1 p').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Comment: @Bjarki, without the `.get()`, the array is jQuery-wrapped, *which still works*, but you have meaningless functions like `find`, `click`, etc, still attached.

Comment: More specifically, `.map()` returns a jQuery object and `.get()` creates a native array from its elements.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you mean the contents of the `<p>` elements, not their value (which is nothing).

```
var text = [];
$('.class1 > p').each(function() {
    text[text.length] = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Box9's solution is more idiomatic jQuery (and probably better), though both are valid.